# Classification ANN stuck at 60%

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I am trying to create a binary classifier on a data set of 10,000. I have tried multiple Activators and Optimizers, however the results are always between 56.8% and 58.9%. Given the fairly steady results over many dozen iterations, I assume the problem is either:

1. My dataset is not classifiable
2. My model is broken

This is the data set: [training-set.csv](http://jasonwpotter.com/training-set.csv)

I may be able to get 2000 more records but that would be it.

**My question is:** is there something in the way my model is constructed that is preventing it from learning to a higher degree?

Note that I am happy to have as many layers and nodes as needed, and time is not a factor in generating the model.

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(r"training-set.csv", index_col=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,0:48].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,48]

#count the input variables
col_count = X.shape[1]

#normalize X
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_scale = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size = 0.2)

# define baseline model
activator = 'linear' #'relu' 'sigmoid' 'softmax' 'exponential' 'linear' 'tanh'
#opt = 'Adadelta' #adam SGD nadam RMSprop Adadelta 
nodes = 1000 
max_layers = 2
max_epochs = 100
max_batch = 32
loss_funct = 'binary_crossentropy' #for binary
last_act = 'sigmoid' # 'softmax' 'sigmoid' 'relu'

def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(nodes, input_dim=col_count, activation=activator))
    for x in range(0, max_layers):
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(nodes, input_dim=nodes, activation=activator))    
    #model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation=last_act)) #model.add(Dense(1, activation=last_act)) 
    # Compile model
    adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss=loss_funct, optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=max_epochs, batch_size=max_batch)

estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = estimator.predict(X_test)

#confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
score = np.sum(cm.diagonal())/float(np.sum(cm))
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it is preferable to use neural networks when your data is strictly homogenous and other models for other heterogeneous data (ensembles methods such as gradient boosting). Moreover, an important part of increasing performance metrics is feature engineering (dropping, transforming and creating new variables). Try reading about univariate feature analysis (such as information values) as well as multivariate methods (PCA, recursive elimination) to gain an idea of how to treat your data prior to fitting a NN.

Comment: Try swapping in a simpler non-neural model just to see how it does. There’s a baseline to help you determine if the issue is the data or the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

1. There is *absolutely no point* in stacking dense layers with linear activations - they only result to a single linear unit; change to `activator = 'relu'` (and just don't bother with the other candidate activation functions in your commented-out list).
2. Do *not* use dropout by default, especially if your model has difficulties in learning (like here); remove the dropout layer(s), and just be ready to put (some of) them back in only in case you see overfitting (you are currently still very far from that point, so this is not something to worry about *now*).

Comment: What about the loss function (e.g. MSE between predictions and ground truths) when stacking dense layers with linear activations: is it still convex?

Comment: @MustafaAydın as said; stack a million linear layers, you'll just get something equivalent to a single linear unit

Comment: yeah but it [turns out](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html) (p. 283, third paragraph) loss functions lose their convexity and it might then be useful to form such networks: "Saxe et al. (2013) provided exact solutions to the complete learning dynamics in such networks and showed that learning in these models captures many of the qualitative features observed in the training of deep models with nonlinear activation functions."

I totally understand your point in the answer; but saying > *absolutely no point* is not exactly right imho.

Comment: @MustafaAydın as quoted, maybe useful as models for study & research of the learning dynamics, but this does not mean they can be used in practice, as attempted here. In any case, this is more of a theoretical question, and this is not the right forum for such discussions.